# How do I stop application switcher button from rotating screen?

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I have the Logitech Wave wireless keyboard, and whenever I accidentally press the "application switcher" button it rotates the screen by 90 degrees. This would only be moderately annoying if it didn't somehow manage to make 90 degrees the new default rotation at boot, requiring me to dig into my xorg.conf file every time it is inadvertently pressed. I would love to be able to disable this button.

I am currently running 13.10, but this behavior occurred on 13.04 as well. Below I have posted the xev output for the button press. Thanks for any help you can afford me!

```
 FocusOut event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

RRScreenChangeNotify event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    root 0x9e, timestamp 1361413, config_timestamp 23509
    size_index 65535, subpixel_order SubPixelUnknown
    rotation RR_Rotate_90
    width 1920, height 1080, mwidth 508, mheight 286

RRNotify event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    subtype XRRCrtcChangeNotifyEvent
    crtc 63, mode None, rotation RR_Rotate_90
    x 0, y 0, width 0, height 0

RRNotify event, serial 51, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    subtype XRROutputChangeNotifyEvent
    output eDP1, crtc None, mode None
    rotation RR_Rotate_0
    connection RR_Connected, subpixel_order SubPixelUnknown
```